# How to fix error in function app publish through visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

I am running into problem when I try to publish the Azure function app from visual studio to Azure.

I picked a sample function from the predefined examples.
It works well when I run the project locally in studio and I can invoke it thr' browser.

However, When I publish it using zip deployment through Studio, it always fails with below error:

> *1>------ Build started: Project: FunctionApp1, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>   1>FunctionApp1 -> C:\Users\<>\source\repos\FunctionApp1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\FunctionApp1.dll
>   2>------ Publish started: Project: FunctionApp1, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>   2>FunctionApp1 -> C:\Users\<>\source\repos\FunctionApp1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\FunctionApp1.dll
>   2>FunctionApp1 -> C:\Users\<>\source\repos\FunctionApp1\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\Out\
>   2>Publishing C:\Users\<>\source\repos\FunctionApp1\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\FunctionApp1 - 20190430110751931.zip to https://functionapp120190430104807.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy...
>   2>**The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://functionapp120190430104807.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code RequestTimeout.**
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========*

What can I do to resolve this?
I am a beginner in Azure, so please excuse me for any obvious thing missed.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

[Zip deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) is a feature of Azure App Service that lets you deploy your function app project to the `wwwroot` directory. The project is packaged as a .zip deployment file. The same APIs can be used to deploy your package to the `d:\home\data\SitePackages` folder.

Set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `0` and restart azure function then it will work fine.

Comment: Hi Joey,

Thanks for your answer.
I tried it, but didn't work.

I am still getting publish error: 
2>The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://functionapp120190430121217.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code RequestTimeout.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: You should be able to pass `?isAsync=true` to the zipdeploy url like `https://functionapp120190430121217.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true`.

Comment: hi..Can you please help me understand where can I specify this parameter? Please excuse me for the ignorance.. I am completely new to Azure

Comment: HI again Joey..

I edited publishProfiles --> deploy xml 
and added ?IsAsync=true to the PublishURL. 
This time the publish was succesful.. but I am not sure which URL should I use to acces the function?  

Below are the logs:

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: FunctionApp2, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>FunctionApp2 -> C:\Users\<userid>\source\repos\FunctionApp2\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\FunctionApp2.dll

Comment: 2>------ Publish started: Project: FunctionApp2, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>FunctionApp2 -> C:\Users\<userid>\source\repos\FunctionApp2\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\FunctionApp2.dll
2>FunctionApp2 -> C:\Users\<userid>\source\repos\FunctionApp2\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\Out\

Comment: 2>Publishing C:\Users\<userid>\source\repos\FunctionApp2\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\FunctionApp2 - 20190501104158833.zip to https://functionapp220190430051613.scm.azurewebsites.net?isAsync=true/api/zipdeploy...
== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped 
== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==

Comment: I have removed lot of extra logs and included only the relevant ones here due to the text limitation

Comment: In publish page of visual studio, it givs me the URL: https://functionapp220190430051613.azurewebsites.net/
When I type it in browser, it says your azure function is up and running.

However, When I pass the query param, it doesnt work..

https://functionapp220190430051613.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?Name=abcd

What I am doing wrong here?

thanks,
Gopal

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what error are you seeing? I am getting 401 while browsing the URL mentioned in the above comment and I believe it is because of the Authorization. You are using Function Authorization in the code and if so you need to  pass a query parameter ?code=<functionKey> in the URL. You can copy the URL from the Portal. It should look like : https://functionapp220190430051613.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?Name=abcd&code=<functionKey>

Comment: Hi @Ketan,

I am getting diffetrent error now.
When I try to publish a project, in the publish window it asks for my azure subscription login even though I am alreayd logged in.
After I enter my credentials, there is no button displayed to proceed.

Same thing happens if I try to create a new publish profile.

If I click on publish button, below error is logged:

Comment: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publishing failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<IsBuildCompletedSuccessfully>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<DefaultCorePublishStep>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

Comment: FWIW, this solved my problem deploying to an app service with error `Error The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://[snip].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code Gateway Timeout`.  In the event anybody else is in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the azure-cli package with pip and the issue resolved.
The issue may come from the broken azure-cli dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I tried to deploy a function to azure function `linux` through visual studio code, I got this error:

```
No route registered for '/api/zipdeploy'
```

[image]

[image]

To solve this problem all you need is to add a new application setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` and set it to true `1`, to your existing function app in the azure portal like the following:

[image]

then the deployment will hopefully work

[image]

**#EDIT**

I tried to create a new function app on azure using visual studio azure function extension, and didn't add that app setting, and the function code got deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If there's anything that errors out on app restart during the deployment, your deployment will fail.

Double-check your configuration blade.  I recently ran into this stubborn, inscrutable error while trying to deploy to a staging slot.  The production slot worked but not staging.

Then I discovered that I had missed one of the configuration settings on the staging slot. Once that was applied I could then zip-deploy successfully to either slot.